# WebClient UploadString returns html code and does not send data

Tags: c#, post, webclient

I'm trying to send some string from a service to a webmethod service with the following code:

```
private void SendRequest(string filePath, string webService)
{ 
    try
    {
         using (var wb = new WebClient())
         {
             string data = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
             data = "data=" + data;
             string res = wb.UploadString(webService, data);                 
         }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logEvents.Write(MyLogClass.LogLevel.Info, "Data not sent " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

For some reason I don't know res is returning the html code of the frontpage.

I was doing this previously with node and my webservice would accept the string without a problem and return 200.

The code of the web service starts as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Data(string data)
```

I've tried formatting the data in several ways and changing the arguments and the URLs are well. The problem is not in the web service since it works fine with my node request. What could it be?

Comment: Have you checked your webservice by debugging what it is returning?

Comment: Sure. With node it returns a JSON with all the data of the request. But with this it doesn't even enter the webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by serializing the data being sent and using WebRequest instead of WebClient.

### Edit

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(webService);
                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                string data = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                var jsonObject = new { data };
                var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
                var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serializedObject);
                var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Please add the code that you used to solve your problem

Comment: I edited the entry to add the code I solved this with

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `Headers` explicitly.

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    wb.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string data = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    data = "data=" + data;
    string res = wb.UploadString(webService, /*"POST",*/ data);
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem. The webservice returns a string which contains
````
"\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\r\n ...
````
Don't know what's wrong yet. All the arguments and vars seem to be right.

Comment: In the output window I get this exception : "System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll"

Comment: check out the contents of the html body. It should mention the exact error that you're getting. Also, confirm if the url (`webservice`) that you're passing, is correct. It looks like you're hitting the homepage url instead of API endpoint url.

Comment: I examined the string it gives back and it simply contains the frontpage content with no single error about the function nor the webservice.

Comment: The URL for the method is accessed form the App.condig file as follows:
private string WebService = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebService"];
and it's specified this way:
<add key ="WebService" value ="http://localhost:30571/myapp.aspx/Data"/>

Comment: Result from `wb.UploadString(webService, /*"POST",*/ data)` is an HTML string since you're posting to an aspx page. Try posting data directly to backend api. Check what function call your aspx makes internally and simply change your url to point to that instead

Comment: As I said in the first entry, the webservice works well with a request made in node in the same fashion (same url, same webservice): It's located in the code behind the aspx web. Why wouldn't it work only when posting from c#?